# Have no idea why Facebook login doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Have no idea why Facebook login doesn't work. Tried all answers to similar questions.The weirdest thing is that there is another app with same settings which works just fine. Maybe there is some kind of update I don't know about.. App runs locally on http://127.0.0.1:8000

Added facebook login product and in value OAuth redirect URLS entered everything possible: localhost,  http://127.0.0.1, http://127.0.0.1:8000

Made app public, tried also creating test app. In app domains it's `localhost` and in Site Urls I tried both `localhost` and `localhost:8000`

EDIT: FB init doesn't even work. So no response to debug or something

And anyways I get this error:

```
Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
```

Id and code is correct. The same works on different project(Checked id, all comas and etc). What else could be theoretically wrong? At least does the error mean what it says `The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains.` ?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, Just started happening with no warning.

I was using .Net Identity 2.0 with Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook 3.0.1 however it seems Facebook may have deprecated support for this.

The only symptom I got when debugging is that the call to AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns a null which is extremely not useful.

In the end I upgraded to the release candidate using the NuGet Package Manager Console command "Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook -Pre"

If you're using .Net with this package then I recommend you test this solution in a staging environment first and see if it fixes the issues (and that it doesn't cause any new issues).

Comment: I am using JS sdk

Comment: @Vinand I've done some more research and it looks like my issue was related to the format of the response token. When using Facebooks graph 2.2 API the response is in URL encoded format, however this API has been switched off with the newer API replying in JSON format. It could be an outdated SDK which uses the older API.

Comment: Congrats, I am using 2.8 . It's most likely related to some error in my another part ofjs code, thought before I submitted but to Facebook report, because even now all seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

it's the FACEBOOK APP PLATFORM in settings

I had my disabled and kept getting error

I enabled the app platform and it works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksxq3.jpg)